# How to save custom field data from a registration form to a custom table when a user creates an account?

Tags: magento2

I added a custom field to the registration form, but only this field I want to save in my custom table, who can help? Thank you

Comment: Hello Robinio , you may try to use event observer i.e add event handler to registration form save event (customer_register_success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Event observer this way
Create a file Module/Custom/etc/events.xml and put this code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="module_custom_save_customer" instance="Module\Custom\Observer\SaveCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Then create a SaveCustomer file in Observer directory Module/Custom/Observer/SaveCustomer.php

```
<?php
namespace Module\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SaveCustomer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $addressFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
        ) { 
        $this->contact_list=$raveHelper->getContactList();
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        // Your custom code here
    }
}
```

To save your custom data in the custom table, can refer the below blog 
https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-create-insert-data-into-the-table-in-magento-2/